# Way to change selection color while calling TextRange.select()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am creating a new add-on for google-slides, I need to highlight text.
I am using the select method in TextRange API. The default highlight color is grey. In case the slide has dark background highlight is not visble

```
const textRange as GoogleAppsScript.Slides.TextRange;
textRange.getRange(start, end).select();
```

This select always highlights in grey color. It is invisible if the background is black or any dark color.

Is it possible to dynamically change the color of selection? So it is always in contrast to the the background.

Comment: Does anyone know a work around or solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

TextRange has more interesting way for highlighting: [TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style). If your add-on code can be transformed to styling instead of selecting, then this solution is for you.

In particular, this small function clears previous highlighted text and makes new one:

```
function highLight() {
  var textRange = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getShapes()[0].getText();
  textRange.getTextStyle().setBackgroundColorTransparent();
  textRange.getRange(131, 146).getTextStyle().setBackgroundColor(255, 255, 150);
}
```

See the result below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Александр Ермолин for the solution! As my add-on deals with selection I would also require to remove this changed TextStyle. Is there any event like mouse click, focus change in SlidesApi on which I can remove the TextStyle?

Comment: As listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers), there is no available triggers for clicks or focus-moves for Slides.